# How to make this redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position thinner?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

I've made a redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position, but would like the circuit to be thinner. I've tried such methods as using more redstone repeaters and changing some paths of the redstone wire, but none of the methods I've tried have worked. Here's a screenshot I took to show what the redstone circuit looks like (Please note the redstone runs underneath the block the lever is on for three blocks in a straight line, and I'm using Minecraft: Wii U Edition on a real Wii U, to help you help me here further):
[image: Redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position]
I forgot to mention the lever must be in the same position, the redstone must be hidden under the lever, the contraption must look the same from the front, the mechanism must be able to be hidden by putting full height blocks around it. Also, you don't have to use the same exact same blocks as me, however; the creeper face uses Green Concrete.

Answer (score 3):

1-wide solution; heavy use of quasi-connectivity and block-dropping so not completely sure if it works on Legacy Console.

[image]

- 16 sticky pistons
- 10 building blocks
- 8 redstone dust
- 5 observers (can be 4 if the input is from top, in that case just mirror the right side on the left).
- 3 doors of any type (possibly 2 if input is from above).

Simplified solution with input from above:

[image]

Also even more compact, but slower and/or more expensive solutions:

[image]

[image]

and a 2-thick version that fully fits within the footprint:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the downvote. I can't see an issue with any of these circuits. Only thing I can imagine is that Legacy Console might very well not have Observers at all, wasn't it discontinued before they were introduced?

Comment: @EgorHans Observers were added to Legacy Console in 2017; it was discontinued only after Update Aquatic (Java's 1.13). It does have quasi-connectivity and block-dropping. Noteblocks may behave differently though - they were changed around 1.14 which never reached L.C.

Comment: Then I officially fail to understand the downvote.

Comment: Neat work! This is for sure a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution for Java Edition & Legacy Console Edition

This solution was built on Java Edition, and *should* work on Legacy Console Edition because it works similarly. If it doesn't, please comment on this post, and I'll see what I can do.

### Materials Required

- 20 sticky pistons
- 22 blocks for redstone to go on
- 12 pieces of redstone dust
- 6 redstone repeaters
- 8 redstone torches

### Solution Images

Image 1:
[image: Back View]
Image 2:
[image: Side View]
Image 3:
[image: Other Side View]
Image 4:
[image: Top View]
Image 5:
[image: Inside View]

### Solution Notes

- There are two pieces of redstone dust on each side, right where the crosshairs are in image 3.
- **Study image 5 carefully.** There are two hidden redstone torches nested inside the circuit. Do not forget them or the circuit won't work.

#### Downsides to This Solution

- Due to the number of redstone torches in this circuit, each "section" of the circuit is delayed, and they don't all pop up at once.

Comment: For the benefit of our readers, I would like to provide an identical question and solution for Bedrock Edition. View the question and answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/369930/250180).

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me, but this one I came up with since asking the question does: https://i.ibb.co/BqPV8Jd/WIN-20200517-10-12-55-Pro.jpg. However, mine isn't fully encasable while still looking the same from the front, down to the position of the lever relative to the position of the contraption (sorry, but I forgot to say that requirement). What can I do now?

Comment: Maybe you built the machine wrong. I might replace the images with a video tutorial. In the meantime, why don't you edit the question to include the requirements you forgot to mention? Click on the EDIT link on the question.
And, may I please ask what is causing the solution to not work? Which pistons are not extending? Can you build my solution and post images of what you see and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Would the video tutorial take my edits into account?

Comment: It definitely would, but I'm afraid I can't see the lever quite clearly. Why don't you post more pictures?