# How to make this redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position thinner? ]

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

*This question is copied from another. This is posted as a duplicate but for Bedrock Edition users, for the benefit of the readers. View the original question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/369922/250180).*

*I do not own the idea for the question, I only am reposting it here but in a different system, so that anyone who wants a solution for Bedrock Edition can have one.*

---

I've made a redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position, but would like the circuit to be thinner. I've tried such methods as using more redstone repeaters and changing some paths of the redstone wire, but none of the methods I've tried have worked. Here's a screenshot I took to show what the redstone circuit looks like now:
[image: Redstone circuit that displays a Minecraft creeper face using pistons if the lever is set to its on position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is for Bedrock Edition, and is different from the answer for Java and Legacy Console Edition. If you need an answer for those editions please see the original question and my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/369924/250180).*

---

## Materials Required

- 14 blocks for redstone to go on
- 5 transparent blocks (glowstone, slabs, etc.)
- 19 pieces of redstone dust

## Solution Images

[image: Screenshot of Solution]

## Solution Notes

- Power any of the four bottom blocks with a repeater input.
- If you would like to, you can move the slab tower to the other side. Just mirror the image.

### Downsides to This Solution

- You must power the circuit using a repeater. If you do not use a repeater the signal strength may run out before reaching the top pistons.